# Cannot find function protect in object Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have made a google script function to update a specific page for multiple different spreadsheets with identical pages. So the function takes the name and position of the sheet to be changed (from a master spreadsheet) and then loops through each of the other spreadsheets and replaces the old specified sheet with the new specified one. My problem is some of the sheets need to be protected but when it replaces them it removes protection.

I've tried to use sheet.protect() but I get "TypeError: Cannot find function protect in object Spreadsheet". I am unaware why since in the google docs I use similar code. I also tried using the getProtections() but it couldn't find the function either.

```
function updatePage(pageName, pagePos) {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetToUp = source.getSheetByName(pageName);

  for (i=0; i < schools.length; i++) {
  //schools[i][1] provides the link to the spreadsheet
    if(schools[i][1] != 0) {
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(schools[i][1]);
      sheetToUp.copyTo(sheet);

      sheet.deleteSheet(sheet.getSheetByName(pageName));

      sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName("Copy of " + pageName));
      sheet.renameActiveSheet(pageName);
      sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName(pageName));
      sheet.moveActiveSheet(pagePos);
      var protection = sheet.protect(); //problem
    }
  }
}
```

It should output a new protected sheet with name pageName at position pagePos in the spreadsheet linked in school[i][1]. It outputs this but its unprotected.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.openById(schools[i][1]);` returns a Spreadsheet, not a Sheet. `protect()` must be called on a Sheet.

Comment: Oh, so i should make a variable for the actual sheet and then protect it. Ty.